# WindowsIdentity.Impersonate in some async scenario leaks identity

Tags: .net, exception, clr

I have the following console app:

```
namespace AsyncConsole
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal static class Program
    {
        #region Private implementation

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
            Program.RunAsync()
                   .GetAwaiter()
                   .GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                using (var threadIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true))
                {
                    if (threadIdentity != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Must not be impersonating {threadIdentity.Name} at the beginning of the request");
                    }
                }

                await Task.Yield();

                using (var threadIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true))
                {
                    if (threadIdentity != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} must not be impersonating {threadIdentity.Name} after first Yield");
                    }
                }

                using (var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                using (identity.Impersonate())
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                }

                using (var threadIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true))
                {
                    if (threadIdentity != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} must not be impersonating {threadIdentity.Name} after disposing impersonation context");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Why does it hit the line

```
throw new InvalidOperationException($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} must not be impersonating {threadIdentity.Name} after first Yield")
```

It looks like `WindowsIdentity` gets stuck in some background thread.

And why does the problem disappear if I comment out the line

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: Impersonation is a per-thread concept, but tasks do not have thread affinity. After an "await", execution can resume on a different thread.

Comment: Execution context does flow across async points.

Comment: Okay, I'll take your word for it that .NET does extra work to preserve identity. But on the other hand, it doesn't seem to be working? In raw Win32, coroutines do not transfer thread identity. Sorry, I can't help you with the .NET-specific part.

Comment: Of course they do. QueueUserWorkItem, I/O Completion Ports, etc. all preserve thread security context.

Comment: Win32 does not transfer security context between threads by default. You have to [ask for it explicitly via WT_TRANSFER_IMPERSONATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-queueuserworkitem). I/O completion ports don't have any option for transferring impersonation context - it's completely the app's responsibility to do that if it needs it.

Comment: You are right about I/O completion ports. But as you said, old thread pool does transfer impersonation if asked.

Comment: It appears that .NET Core and .NET Framework behave differently with respect to impersonation. See extended discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24977).

Comment: My understanding is API  behaves the same, implementation is different.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [updated documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=netframework-4.8) clarifying that WindowsIdentity.Impersonate is not safe to be used in async scenarios, while WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated is.